# Call dynamic function from ng-click

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

I have the following 2 functions/classes

```
function Availability(){    
    this.Click = function (){
        alert("Availability");
    }
}

function Help(){
    this.Click = function (){
        alert("Help");
    }
}
```

I've created the following module:

```
var Gadgetory = angular.module("Gadgetory", []);
```

and the following controller:

```
var ToolbarController = Gadgetory.controller('ToolbarController', ['$scope',
    function ($scope)
    {
        $scope.greeting = 'Gadgetory!';
        $scope.Gadgets = [
            { name: "Availability", icon: "available.png", object: new Availability() },
            { name: "Help", icon: "help.png", object: new Help() }
        ];
    }
]);
```

Now in my html I want to call the click method of each gadget in my dictionary, something like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="gadget in Gadgets">
    <img ng-src="/Gadgets/{{gadget.icon}}" ng-click="{{gadget.object}}.Click()"/>
</div>
```

but this fails to work, can you help me?

Comment: what is the resulting code that is generated?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You shouldn't include `{{` and `}}` instructions when calling a method — they are used when printing values to the screen or setting values to element attributes. For calling methods and manipulating data just use the plain JavaScript syntax:

```
<div ng-repeat="gadget in Gadgets">
    <img ng-src="/Gadgets/{{gadget.icon}}" ng-click="gadget.object.Click()"/>
</div>
```